# jpa mapping of embedded class attribute to a database column

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

Recently I am working with Java JPA. I am using NetBeans 8.0.2 IDE. EclipseLink implementation of JPA is default to NetBeans. As Database I am using MySql Database.

I want an Embedded Entity With two fields. I want both of them to be saved in database.

Here is my code.

```
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Embedded
private Code code;

@Embeddable
class Code implements Serializable{
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "code_no")
short codeNo;

@OneToOne(optional = false)
private Language language;
```

}

I want there will be a **code_no** *SmallInt* field and a **language_id** *SmallInt* field in the database.
But actually it gives me a **language_id** field with *SmallInt* and **Code** field with *longblob*.

Any help how can I do that? If you need I can give you the full source.

thanks

Comment: I wouldn't have thought that using '@Basic' and '@Embedded' on the same field was a good idea....Try removing the @Basic annotation.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have removed @Basic, still no help. I have posted another question writing more details, though i am facing different exception now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30993580/jpa-facing-exception-in-creating-database-tables-with-embedded-entity